# rendering html dynamically using Aurelia

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, aurelia

I have a requirement where I get the string in the form of HTML tags and it changes on a button click. On button click, I am changing the value of the binding element.

```
<div id="htmString">${htmlTag}</div>
```

and the content in htmlTag is

```
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

How can I skip writing document.getElement in the view model and still compile the HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to bind to the innerHTML property like this:
`<div id="htmString" innerhtml.bind="htmlTag"></div>`

So any time htmlTag changes it will get rendered inside your div.